# X-Mouse Button Control: How to set double-click to close browser tab?

Tags: browser, browser-tabs, double-click, xmouse

Firefox and Vivaldi web browsers have this feature built-in: You can **double left-click on the tab title** (not "anywhere" on the web page) to **close that tab**.

I want to use [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to do this in Opera (and any other web browser later). I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Can someone please give me a tutorial on how to set that up using X-Mouse Button Control software?

*(I'm using a standard **touchpad** on a Dell laptop, not an actual mouse or some add-on device.)*

Comment: And just how do you suppose X-Mouse Button Control can be aware that the cursor is located over a tab title box?

Comment: I have no idea..yet. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: If anyone has used other similar software, could this be accomplished with something else? I found this list [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/changing-and-customizing-your-mouse-buttons-actions/) on a few similar applications.

Comment: If someone knows how Firefox and Vivaldi implement this feature, that could give some good insight into how to simulate it in other browsers.  Just an idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the author of X-Mouse Button Control software and he said that this **cannot be done**.

In his words:

> XMBC can't detect and remap a double click, only individual button clicks.

https://forums.highrez.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=4377

Comment: If someone knows of any other tools that can detect and remap double click, please post in a comment!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work for you with X-Mouse Button Control (XMBC):

(1) select the Layer 1 tab within the XMBC software;

(2) you can name Layer 1 in its title box if you like but it's not required;

(3) then beside Left Button select its drop down menu and with it select Button Held Custom;

(4) then to the right of this same drop down menu is a small square button, select it and a window titled "Button Held Time Dependent Actions" will open. It's within this BHTDA window you'll create a press & hold time for this Left Button so that when it's held down for that long (say 500 milliseconds), that button will automatically perform a "double click" at that moment just as if you actually had double-clicked your left mouse button;

(5) Now, in this BHTDA window (you can enter a name in it for this customization if you want but it's not required) to the right of the words "Normal Click" is a drop down menu; it it select Left Click;

(6) In the next row down mouse-click the box next to "Held for" then to the right set your hold-down time (or use the default time that's already typed in there--you can modify it again later if you want to change it)... then a bit further right is a drop down menu--in it select "Double Click";

(7) now at the bottom of the BHTDA window select the OK button and the BHTDA windows closes;

(8) now you're back in the main window, press its Apply Button, then press its Close Button and your done!

I hope my directions are clear because I just ran out of time for this task.  I'm sure this description should clear all this up for you in so far as gaining a basic understanding of how to use this mouse software.

Comment: Thanks..I want to clarify: I'm not trying to simulate the "double click" part. I actually want to do the double click, that's what I've been struggling with. Once the real double click happens, I need it to close that tab (Ctrl+W), but only when I double click on that tab title, not just anywhere on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is even possible..I *don't* want to "double click" anywhere and have it simulate Ctrl+W. It should only happen on the "name" of the tab, like in Firefox and Vivaldi.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fixes OP's problem, but there is a way to use double click in order to preform actions.

Just make two layers. Have the button you want to do the double click preform a layer change. Then find that same button on the second layer and have it preform the the designated double click action.

Now you have to go through two layers. So if I want middle mouse to preform close browser, make it so...

1.) click middle mouse button = Open layer # and original mouse click function (middle click)

2.)Now in the second layer, middle click will close the browser tab. Then just change the layer to revert back after 1 second!

[Layer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQuwr.png)

[Layer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZA5M.png)